# How do I access an element in a list within a column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, extract, element

My goal is to extract elements from a list within a column to new columns.

[image]

I have tried using the common bracket notation:

```
df['lat'] = df['query'][0]
 
df['lon'] = df['query'][1]
```

The error I get is: "ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (1)"

What is the error trying to say?

Comment: Can you write the dataframe as well instead of the image?

Comment: Use `.str` accessor. `df['lat'] = df['query'].str[0]`

Comment: Thanks Psidom, suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try out,

```
df['lat'], df['lon'] = df['query'].str[0], df['query'].str[1]
```